# Push notification not working register

Tags: ios, angularjs, notifications, push, ionic-framework

This feature did not work in my code, I'm trying to get the token device on iOS but it still fails.

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
     window.plugins.pushNotification.register(
     function(token){
       alert(token);
     },
     function(){
       alert('Error al registrarse en el servidor APNS');
     },
     {
       "badge":"true",
       "sound": "true",
       "alert": "true",
       "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
     });
 });
```

Nor send me any errors, testing with gapDebug. Can anyone help me with this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should build/sign your app using addhoc. Install the signed app on real device [via testflight, for example]. Then see if you get your device registered. "It never will when running in debugger on your phone from xCode"

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I really did not understand much I Might explain more detail? The firm is made addhoc